# How to pass props from component A to component C

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

Here I want to pass props from A to c. Basically, I have created a function in the A component and aspecting an argument from the C component. but this does not work. so, please tell me How do I pass arguments in C to A.

```
import React from 'react'
    import B from './B'
    
    const A = () => {
        const displayData=(parameter)=>{
           // .......... somecode 
              }
        return (
            <div>
                <B 
                sendData ={displayData} 
                />
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default A
    
    
    
    //component B
    
    import React from 'react'
    import C from './C'
    
    const B = ({sendData}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <C //component c
                sendData = {sendData}
                />
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default B
    
    //component c
    
    import React from 'react'
    
    const C = ({sendData}) => {
    
        sendData(argument);
        return (
            <div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default C
```

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you don't want to pass it through B? Because your code appears to work just fine the way it is.

Comment: Use React Context

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit unspecific.It would be very nice if you could be more specific on how you call and use these components and what you try to accomplish.In short a bit of "working" code would be nice.

At first you might want to wrap the function in Component C in a useEffect Hook. Because I do not know if "argument" is filled when the function is called so like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   sendData(argument)
}, [argument])
```

So it will be fired everytime argument changes.

Then I guess it is called "display data" because it changes a value and displays it so you might want your app to rerender when the datachanges? So in A you declare a setState function. It isn´t that easy to assume what you try to accomplish.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(standardValue);
const displayData = () => {
     //your logic
     setData(the preprocessed value);
}
```

The next thing you could do to bypass component B is using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
With this you can Exchange Data between all the components that are wrapped in the provider.
That solution might be a bit overkill for just one argument.

If you want to make it as easy as possible something like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) could be in your favor. This is a context for your whole application. There you can store all stateful data, change it and use it in every component that is connected to the store.